# Constrain the add of only one product between associated products of a Grouped Product

Tags: product, ce-1.9.0.1, grouped-products, downloadable

In Magento 1.9.0.1, I have a product that I can ship **or** I can download so I created 1 simple product and 1 downloadable product with no visibility in Catalog. Then I created a Grouped product and I associated the above mentioned products.

This works, but customers in product page must manual insert "1" in quantity field of interest product and then finally add to card.

I'ld like constrain customers so they choose one of the 2 products simply by clicking over and then add to cart the selected product.

How can I do?

Answer (score 1):

This would work better with a configurable product. Create an attribute called `delivery_method` and give it two options: **download** and **shipping**.
Set this attribute to *use for configurable product* and create a configurable product with it adding the above mentioned simple products.

This should get the trick done.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried to do as you write but I only able to create "Simple Associated Product" inside a Configurable Product. Or Am I wrong something?